# Nuget package with debug symbols successfully pushed but it is not available

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, debug-symbols

1. I successfully created both regular nuget package and nuget package with pdb files. Followe instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages
2. With this command:
   **nuget push myPackage-Beta.nupkg xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx -Source nuget.org -SymbolSource https://nuget.smbsrc.net -Verbosity detailed -Timeout 600**
   nuget packages are successfully pushed to nuget.org and nuget.smbsrc.net. No warnings, no errors just info about successfull pushe to both servers.
3. Now package is public and available for download on nuget.org, but that is not the case for nuget.smbsrc.net. Here, nuget package is not listed at all.I was checking with this command:
   **nuget list -AllVersions -Prerelease -Source https://nuget.smbsrc.net**
   I tried this command with package name as well with printing all packages in the txt file, and my package is not present
4. Also I added https://nuget.smbsrc.net in VS in list of symbol locations but symbol package is not loaded

So, I am puzzled what is happening.  What am I missing to do? I appriciate any help or suggetsion.

Answer (score 0):

> With this command:
>   nuget push myPackage-Beta.nupkg xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx -Source nuget.org -SymbolSource https://nuget.smbsrc.net -Verbosity detailed -Timeout 600

You should push the package "myPackage-Beta.nupkg" and "myPackage-Beta.symbols.nupkg" to nuget.org and https://nuget.smbsrc.net **individually**.

Detail steps:

1. Push regular package to nuget.org:

   `nuget push myPackage-Beta.nupkg xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx -Source nuget.org`
2. Push **symbols package** to https://nuget.smbsrc.net：

   `nuget push myPackage-Beta.symbols.nupkg -Source https://nuget.smbsrc.net`

After those steps, we could list the version of symbols package:

```
nuget list PackageName -AllVersion -Prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that earlier, but result is the same. I get info that package is successfully pushed to https://nuget.smbsrc.net but when try to list it,I get "No packages found."  Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: nuget push MyPackage.x.x.x.x-Beta.symbols.nupkg -Source https://nuget.smbsrc.net   
Pushing MyPackage.x.x.x.x-Beta.symbols.nupkg to 'https://nuget.smbsrc.net'...
  POST https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/create-verification-key/MyPackage/x.x.x.x-Beta
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/create-verification-key/MyPackage/x.x.x.x-Beta 1005ms
  PUT https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package/
  OK https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package/ 820232ms
Your package was pushed.

Comment: @Sergio, what is your list command line? How about the result when you use my list command line?

Comment: nuget list MyPackage -AllVersions -Prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net           
No packages found.

Comment: @Sergio, that strange. I have also push a -Beta package, it works fine. Could you list my package with the command line "nuget list LSGTestNuGetPackage -AllVersion -Prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net", if you can get the package list, please share your list command line with package name to us, so that we can test it on my side. Screenshots will be more clear.

Comment: I am able to see your three prerelease packages but not mine. Here is the command that I ma using for my package **nuget list Ortc -AllVersions -Prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net**

Comment: @Sergio, thanks for reply. I have test your command line, got the same result "Not Found". Since you can see my packages but not your`s, it seems this issue is more related to your package itself. How did you create it and have you try create a new symbols package to test. Besides, if you do mind, you can share your package with oneDirve, I will help you check it.